# Change mouse cursor to hand (pointer) in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny, dt

How I can change the mouse over icon to **pointer** (hand) when user hover over data table cells.I am having 4 columns in a datatable and the 4th column row cells is diplaying tool tip on mouse over. I need to change the cursor icon to pointer when tool tip is displayed.I think this can be achieved through dt package options & JS but no success till now,Any Tips to achieve the same in **R Shiny UI**.

Answer (score 5):

Used **CSS Script** with rowCallback feature of DT Package to achieve this.Here is the code for iris datatable :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
DT::dataTableOutput("irisTable")
),
server = function(input, output) {

output$irisTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(datasets::iris, 
                options = list(rowCallback = JS(
                  "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
                  "var full_text = aData[1] + ','+ aData[2] + ',' + aData[3] + ','+ aData[4];",
                  "$('td:eq(5)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);", # Tool Tip
                  "$('td:eq(5)', nRow).css('cursor', 'pointer');", # Cursor icon changes to hand (pointer) on Hover
                  "}")
                )
  )

})
}
)
```

Comment: Nice answer string, would you also be able to help me do this for a renderimage? It produces a crosshair, but I would prefer to have the hand symbol to match the style of all my buttons

Comment: Nevermind, found a solution. Was a lot easier than I thought. 
tags$style( '#inputId_image { cursor: pointer; }')

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is struggling with showing a hand pointer over datatable cells, you can simulate hyperlink behavior within a Shiny DT by passing the argument, cursor='pointer', into the formatting function, DT::formatStyle(), and then calling input${output_table}_cell_clicked. Working example below:

```
library(magrittr)    
library(shiny)
library(DT)
    
    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        DT::dataTableOutput("irisTable")
      ),
      server = function(input, output) {
        
            
        output$irisTable <- DT::renderDT({
          DT::datatable(iris, selection = 'none') %>% 
            DT::formatStyle(., which('Sepal.Width' %in% names(iris))+1 , color = 'blue', cursor='pointer')
        })
        
          shiny::observeEvent(input$irisTable_cell_clicked, {
            print(input$irisTable_cell_clicked)
          })
          
      }
    )
```