# Valuebox cursor change

Tags: r, shiny

So I am struggling with an aspect of R Shiny, and I hope you can help. Essentially, as part of my app I am building there are certain summary boxes where I have added an `onclick()` function that changes the table displayed below. However, it is not obvious to the user that you can click these boxes. I would like to ideally change the cursor when over the clickable area to a hand (like R Shiny does for drop down menus etc). I have tried implementing the answers found here:

[Change mouse pointer to hand in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836947/change-mouse-cursor-to-hand-pointer-in-r-shiny)

[Cursor change while hovering over shiny widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112903/cursor-change-while-hovering-over-shiny-widget)

However, the first relates to a table and I cannot figure out how to re-write it for a box. The second link is much more promising, but whenever I implement it I can only seem to make the entire page turn into a different cursor. I only want the specific boxes to show a clickable cursor.

I have provided an extract for the part of the code I am using (where the various bit are on different scripts). I have left the actual content of the box empty, since it is not important, but it would be something along the lines of the mean, median etc.

```
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "summaryStatistics",
    uiOutput('summary_stats')
)

output$summary_stats = renderUI({
  div(
    fluidRow(
      valueBoxOutput("W", width = 3),
      valueBoxOutput("X", width = 3),
      valueBoxOutput("Y", width = 3),
      valueBoxOutput("Z", width = 3)
    )
})

output$X = renderValueBox({
})
```

I hope I have managed to get everything pertinent on here; apologies if I have missed anything. Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all boxes with this CSS :

`.small-box {cursor: pointer;}`

or only the box with specified ids (selected with `#` in CSS) with :

`#W .small-box, #X .small-box, #Y .small-box, #Z .small-box {cursor: pointer;}`

Available options for cursor are listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor).

With your app, it gives :

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # All box with cursor = pointer
    # tags$style(".small-box {cursor: pointer;}"),
    # Only box with IDs X, Y, Z, W
    tags$style("#W .small-box, #X .small-box, #Y .small-box, #Z .small-box {cursor: pointer;}"),
    uiOutput('summary_stats')
  ),
  title = "Dashboard example"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$summary_stats <- renderUI({
    div(
      fluidRow(
        valueBoxOutput("W", width = 3),
        valueBoxOutput("X", width = 3),
        valueBoxOutput("Y", width = 3),
        valueBoxOutput("Z", width = 3)
      )
    )
  })

  output$X <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(value = 1, subtitle = "X")
  })
  output$Y <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(value = 1, subtitle = "Y")
  })
  output$Z <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(value = 1, subtitle = "Z")
  })
  output$W <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(value = 1, subtitle = "W")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```